# Publishing Asp.net core 3.1.3 with react + authentication to Azure Linux App Service not working

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, azure-app-service-plans, azure-linux

I am trying to deploy an asp.net core react app with framework version net core 3.1.3 to an Azure Linux App Service from visual studio but for some reason after the deploy finishes in visual studio, the azure url still shows that I have not deployed any code.

I tried a brand new simple web app, using the default template for an asp.net web application and it properly deploys.

Then I tried to create a brand new out of the box react template with authentication and the url of my website is back to say that I dont have any code deployed yet.

Apparently there’s an issue specific to that template that makes azure think theres no deployed code after deployment completes.

Visual studio doesnt throw any errors but it says publish succeeded and that web app is ready to use.

[image: visual studio output]

Comment: Apparently this is only happening to apps that have authentication. Deploying the simple templates with No Authentication selected works just fine. Digging more.

Comment: Finding it weird that the documentation for deploy to Azure Linux App Service explicitely tells not to use authentication.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-to-linux

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the cause of the issue was the fact that the template registers  IdentityServer 4 for authentication in the startup.cs,

Identity does not only register itself, but it tries to access the database it is given to handle the user accounts. I wasnt expecting that since I was just testing the deployment of the app but wasnt testing data access yet.

Since the error happened on startup, the application was never up and running.

I commented IdentityServer registration just to test and the deployment worked fine.

So, if you are registering identity server, make sure the database it tries to access is available at the moment of starting up your website in the azure servers.

[image]